# Flash Guitar Tuner

Tags: flash, audio, microphone

I am attempting to make a Guitar Tuner in flash using the microphone. I need to know how to read the samples from the microphone. I am assuming I would use the SAMPLEDATA Event. But I'm not quite sure how.

Also does flash use 16 or 32 bit for reading?

Just need a push in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation has a good example that might serve as a starting point, it listens to a microphone and plays back the audio it hears:

[Flash AS3 SampleData event documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Microphone.html#event%3asampleData)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Just what I need to get started.